# the partial derivation of matrix

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative

I would like to get the derivation of the matrix $a^T(LL^T)^{-1}b$ in terms of L, what I got is $-2L(LL^T)^{-1}ab^T(LL^T)^{-1}$,is it right? if not, why?

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ constants? Also, what do you mean by $a'$ - $a^T$?

Comment: a and b also matrix,typo,it's also transpose